# Mac OSX printer color profile is wrong

Tags: printing, color-profiles, macos-highsierra

I have a desktop (Windows 10) computer and a Macbook Pro (2016 version, OSX 10.13). My printer is Fuji Xerox cm115w the official software was installed in both operation systems.

One same pdf form was downloaded from internet to do print test. In Windows, the color is OK and shows the light gray shadow properly. But in OSX the shadow is too bright, it can't even be seen by native eyes.

I suspect that the color profile for the printer is wrong. But how can I fix this?

Comment: You first need to know if your screen profile is correct, what profile is attached to the image file & whether your output software is compensating for that, converting the colour space or passing it through untouched. Right now we don't have enough info to guess on.

Comment: @Tetsujin The problem is that I don't even know how to check the items you suggested.  I am new to OSX.

Comment: First - are all your screens calibrated? If not, you will never actually know which version is correct.